# Complex potential in quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, operators, schroedinger-equation, hamiltonian

I'm reading Quantum Mechanics by Griffiths. In the solution to one of the problems in this book they claimed that if the time-independent wavefunction $\psi$ solves $-\frac{\hbar}{2m}\frac{\partial^2\psi}{\partial x^2}+V\psi=E\psi$, then $\psi^{*}$ also satisfies the differential equation. I don't see why this is true. This is only true if both $E$ and $V$ are real. $E$ must be real in order for the wavefunction to be normalized. But why is $V$ also real?

Comment: Aren't you insisting on a Hermitian hamiltonian?

Comment: E is real because E_i-E_f represents the "experimental readout" and the difference is a classical energy. The entire construction of quantum mechanics starts with the fact that all we can measure are distributions of quanta with classical energies and momenta.

Comment: Maybe you are early in Griffiths and haven't gotten to the operator language, so just to expand on Cosmas's comment, your logic turns out to be a bit backward. We need $E$ to be real for all eigenstates $\psi$. It turns out that, to guarantee that $E$ is real, the Hamiltonian operator $H=-\frac{\hbar}{2m}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}+V$ must be *Hermitian*, meaning $H^\dagger=H$ (where $^\dagger$ is an operation that means "transpose and take the complex conjugate"). This condition ends up implying that $V$ is real. So, simplifying, if $V$ were not real then $E$ would be complex in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A complex potential $V$ would lead to a non-hermitian Hamiltonian $H$ which means the time evolution operator $$U=e^{-iHt}$$ wouldn't be unitary and thus probability would not be conserved. That's a bit of an issue.

Answer (score 0):

To understand why the potential energy in quantum mechanics is real, we need to trace it back to its introduction. Looking at [Landau & Lifshitz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Course_of_Theoretical_Physics) third edition, §17, it can be read that in classical (non-relativistic) mechanics the interaction of particles is described by additive term in the Hamiltonian - potential energy of interaction. Adding up such term to Hamiltonian operator in quantum mechanics describes particle interaction as well, though, it's actually not a result of quantum mechanics principles and it needs to be considered as an experimental outcome.

This way, the real nature of potential energy in quantum mechanics is a purely experimental result which dates back to the introduction of the potential energy in quantum mechanics, particularly, in the Hamiltonian operator.